# Camera, second screen, audio and microphone not working

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, multiple-monitors, dell

While trying to fix my inbuilt camera that only showed a black screen I have also loss access to the computer audio (audio dummy), the microphone and my computer can't detect the second screen anymore.

I think I might have mixed up the drivers. Did this ever happen to anyone?